# Ajax Form submit both input data and file no response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form, which need to submit a file and input data. I use jQuery validator to check the form then submit.

```
<form method="POST" id="form_1" action="../api.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Amy" readonly="readonly">
    <input id="fileBox" class="fileUpload" type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="isSubmit" value="1"/>
</form>

<a id="btnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0)">Submit</a>
```

```js
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    if ($("#form_1").valid()){ //jquery validator to check the form
        $("#form_1").submit(function() {
            var formData = new FormData(($this)[0]);
            $ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../../api.php",
                data: { 
                    action:"formSubmit", 
                    formData:formData
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Why no response when I click `btnSubmit`? What's wrong with my code? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The issue is because you're attaching a submit handler to the form when the button is clicked you're not actually submitting the form at all.

Comment: Also note that you don't define `$this` anywhere, and you're getting a DOMElement from a DOMElement wrapped in a jQuery object. Instead just call `new FormData(this)`.

Comment: thank you Rory McCrossan but i still get an error "illegal invocation". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$("#form_1").submit(function(){ ... });
```

does not trigger the submit, it only registers event handler that reacts to submit. Instead of that you should register your event handler first, and in your click event just trigger it:

```
// at first you register event handler for when the form is submitted
$("#form_1").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData(($this)[0]);
    $ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../api.php",
        data: { action:"formSubmit", formData:formData}
    }).done(function(data){
         data = $.parseJSON(data);
    });
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    if($("#form_1").valid()){ 
        // inside click event handler you trigger form submission
        $("#form_1").trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: @SFY I believe in your HTML you don't need `href` attribute in `a` tag, because it is handled by jQuery. Also for urls you should define them not as relative to the document, but as relative to home page, so it should be e.g. `/api.php` instead of `../api.php` or `../../api.php`. The rest of HTML depends on your application

Comment: thank you i can trigger submit now , but there's an error "illegal invocation" when i clicked submit. any thing else goes wrong?

Comment: @SFY I think the data that you are trying to submit is not handled correctly. See comment to your question that you do not declare `$this` anywhere. Try fixing that first.

Comment: I changed in to new FormData((this)[0]) already . still same error .  this error should come from api.php or the js file?

Comment: also do I need to add these two  "processData:false" and "contentType:false" in the ajax also ?

Comment: @SFY I suggest asking a new question about the recent issues that you are having. Your original question was why the event handler was not working, and additional questions are not related to that.